# Ansible variable interpolation in list of dictionaries

Tags: yaml, ansible

Variable interpolation is not working in some nested context.

If I'm including a vars file that has something like this:

```
some_current_user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
some_user_vars: [{blah: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"}] # oops!
```

The second variable is not interpolated as expected. Is there a way to fix this?

This task

```
- debug: var=some_current_user
- debug:
    msg: "blah - {{ item.blah }}"
  with_items: "{{ some_user_vars }}"
```

results in

```
TASK [debug]
*******************************************************************
ok: [my.host] => {
    "some_current_user": "myuser"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [my.host] => (item={u'blah': None}) => {
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "msg": "blah - "
        }, 
        "module_name": "debug"
    }, 
    "item": {
        "blah": null
    }, 
    "msg": "blah - "
}
```

Comment: What is your ansible version? Works for me. `(item={'blah': u'myuser'})`

Comment: I'm using ansible version `2.0.1.0`

Comment: Yes, it fails in 2.0.1.0 but works in 1.9.2

Comment: It works now in 2.1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a bug and is resolved in ansible 2.1.0.0.